# Do I have to create 2 different views for search function in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP and want to have a search tool in the website I write using it. I have the search() function in the controller where basically all the logic goes. So in the view folder I have created a search.ctp file where I wrote the code for the form to fill in the search details. But I cant figure out where to write the code that will show the search results. Should I create another .ctp file and, if so, then how can I connect this file with the search() function since it would have another name(not search.ctp)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not necessary, but you'll have to make a switch in both your controller function and your view whether or not your are showing results or not.

For example, in your Controller you would have this:

```
function search()
{
   if (!empty($this->data))
   {
     // .. do search, gather results
     $this->set('results', $results);
   }
}
```

`$this->data` is only filled if you enter a form.

In your view, you would write something like:

```
if (isset($results))
{
   // print table with results
}
else
{
   // show search form
}
```

It's more a matter of taste if you want a single function/url or not. Personally I prefer separate views as it reduces the number of if/elses. Also, a search form may be placed on many pages while you will only have one search result page.

Answer (score 0):

I think better would be using two separate views:

```
function search()
{
   if (!empty($this->data))
   {
     // .. do search, gather results
     $this->set('results', $results);
     return $this->render('search_results');
   }
   return $this->render('search_form');
}
```

then create two ctp files search_results.ctp (with results table) and search_form.ctp (with search form)

You should use as little as possible logic in views